# sympy raise matrix elements to power?

Tags: sympy

I have a `sympy.Matrix` with symbolic elements.  I would like to raise each element to the power of `k` for some `k`, symbolic or numeric.  Is there an operation that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `applyfunc` for this:

```
In [2]: M = Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: M.applyfunc(lambda e: e**2)
Out[3]: 
⎡1  4 ⎤
⎢     ⎥
⎣9  16⎦
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#operations-on-entries